# Get L.marker individual attributes

Tags: leaflet, angular

I am using this code to draw points on the map:

```
coordsArray.push(lat);
coordsArray.push(lng);
marker = L.marker(coordsArray, {
    icon: myIcon,
    clickable: true,
    draggable: 'false',
    title: layerStringToJson.properties.id
}).bindPopup(coordinates).addTo(map).on('click', onClick);
```

And I have this method to get individual marker properties:

```
function onClick(e) {
      //marker=layerStringToJson.properties;
      console.log(marker._latlng)
  }
```

But when I click on the markers, I always have the same result, always the same coordinates instead of the coordinates of every single marker.

Anyway the pop up shows the correct coordinates.

How can I get the individual properties of each marker?

Comment: See https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.5.0.html#event-target (hint: do `console.log(e)`) and also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work (think about what's the value of `marker` then the event handler runs).

Answer (score 1):

2 options, for a single marker:

```
var lat = 43;
var lng = -76;

 var marker = L.marker([lat,lng]).bindPopup(lat.toString()+", "+lng.toString()).addTo(map);
 marker.addTo(map);
```

For multiple markers use a feature group:

```
var myMarkers = L.featureGroup();

    // create loop here to add each marker to the featuregroup
    var marker = L.marker([lat,lng]).bindPopup(lat.toString()+", "+lng.toString()).addTo(map);
    //add the marker to the featuregroup
    myMarkers.addLayer(marker);
    //end loop

myMarkers.addTo(map);
```